# Clip a shapefile into rectangle shape

Tags: qgis, arcmap, geoprocessing

I have a global Vector file.

[image]
I want to clip it to country's level. But the file is very large and it is taking too much time. I want to first clip it to a rectangle as marked below, then use that rectangle shapefile to clip to country level. How to clip the shapefile into a rectangle (polygon) preferably in ArcMap?
[image]

Comment: What format is the world vector file?  Does it have attributes that identify the county of interest

Comment: If you have large multipolygons try [Multiparto To Singlepart](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm) then clip the output. Afterwards you can Dissolve the singleparts back to multiparts if you need to

Comment: @nmtoken No attributes to identify country of interest.

Comment: Been a while since I've used arcmap, but can't you just zoom to your country of interest and clip to extent?

Answer (score -1):

Select your region and make a temporary layer out of the selected features.
Then clip that temporary layer to your rectangle.